# Adding Class to Anchor

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div id="tree-backend" class="treeview">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item node-tree-backend" data-nodeid="0" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;">
            <span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"/>
            <span class="icon node-icon fa fa-user"/>
            <a href="http://bioplast/admin/menu/detail?id=3" style="color:inherit;">User</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item node-tree-backend" data-nodeid="1" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;">
            <span class="indent"/>
            <span class="icon glyphicon"/>
            <span class="icon node-icon none"/>
            <a href="http://bioplast/admin/menu/detail?id=5" style="color:inherit;">Group</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to add class to the anchor elements using jQuery .addClass method like this:

```
$(".treeview .list-group .list-group-item a").each(function(){
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("user-action-btn-1");
    };
 })
```

But it didn't work.

Please help me..

Comment: Why the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)? There is no element after the `<a>`

Comment: I have omitted the if and next, but it's still not working..

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because... https://jsfiddle.net/huLxpus3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code if you want to add same class on all anchor  present in .treeview class

$(".treeview .list-group .list-group-item a").addClass('user-action-btn-1');